# how Activiti Enters the waiting task and perform an operation

Tags: activiti, bpmn

I want to achieve this goals,

when the process moves to a node, it stopsat a place, to send a message to the MQ, when receiving subscriber finished the message, the process continues.

which task can I use？Receive Task？if so，how can I know the task arrival.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Receive Task. To know that task is staretd use execution listener.

```
<receiveTask id="waitTask" name="Wait Task">
    <extensionElements>
        <activiti:executionListener event="start" class="SendMessageExecutionListener"></activiti:executionListener>
      </extensionElements>
</receiveTask>
```

Listener must implement `ExecutionListener` interface

```
public class SendMessageExecutionListener implements ExecutionListener {

    @Override
    public void notify(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {
        //send message here
    }
}
```

And when subsriber handles message signal process to continue. 

See more details in Activiti User Guide [Java Receive Task](http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnReceiveTask) section.